# Spiral matrix generator skips rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, spiral

I wrote a code that is supposed to generate a spiral pattern of characters. It does generate a spiral, but for some reason, it skips the outermost column, the bottommost row, and the leftmost column (I'll leave an example output below). I can't figure out why this is happening on my own. I do check whether the cell two steps ahead is filled. Only if it is, we should make a turn, essentially creating the spiral.

```
def asterisk_spiral(size):
    matrix = [[' ' for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]

    row, col = 0, 0
    directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]
    direction = 0

    for i in range(1, size * size // 2):
        matrix[row][col] = '*'

        next_row, next_col = row + directions[direction][0], col + directions[direction][1]
        next_next_row, next_next_col = row + 2 * directions[direction][0], col + 2 * directions[direction][1]
        
        if (
            0 <= next_row < size
            and 0 <= next_col < size
            and 0 <= next_next_row < size
            and 0 <= next_next_col < size
            and matrix[next_row][next_col] == ' '
            and matrix[next_next_row][next_next_col] != '*'
        ):
            row, col = next_row, next_col
        else:
            # turn
            direction = (direction + 1) % 4
            row, col = row + directions[direction][0], col + directions[direction][1]

    return matrix

def print_spiral(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print(' '.join(row))

size = 9

spiral_matrix = asterisk_spiral(size)
print_spiral(spiral_matrix)
```

Result:

```
[['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' '],
 [' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

whereas expected matrix is:

```
[['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
 ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]
```

Comment: The criterion `0 <= next_next_row < size` means that you will never reach the last row, because that criterion fails when you are in the penultimate row, therefore you turn when you reach the penultimate row. (Same goes for columns.) You probably need different logic for "cell two steps ahead is out of bounds" as opposed to "cell two steps ahead is filled".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `if` condition `0 <= next_row < size` is true, but `0 <= next_next_row < size` is not true, your logic will trigger a turn, but that means that for the first few lines the turn is made *before* hitting the boundary of the square, i.e. one step too early.

Instead you should have this logic:

*"When the next cell in the current direction exists, and *it is not so* that one step further there is an asterisk, then go on in the same direction".*

That means the `if` condition could look like this:

```
        if (
            0 <= next_row < size
            and 0 <= next_col < size
            and not (0 <= next_next_row < size
                     and 0 <= next_next_col < size
                     and matrix[next_next_row][next_next_col] == '*')
        ):
```

Once you have corrected this, you'll notice another issue: the loop doesn't make enough iterations. The `for` statement should be corrected to this:

```
    for i in range(size + size * size // 2):
```

Depending how you want the output to look for when `size` is an *even* number, you may want to reduce that by one iteration. If so, change it to this:

```
    for i in range(1 - size % 2, size + size * size // 2):
```

Choose whichever of the two suits your needs for the case where `size` is even.

Comment: Thanks for this. After the fix I found there are many more problems with the algorithm, for example if I replace the for loop with any from answer, then change the direction like this `row, col = 0, size - 1`, `[(0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1)]` to go anticlockwise there seem to be strange things happening with output matrix which I goin to investigate with debugger next time. But for now, to fix the behaviour after changing direction, I changed loop `for i in range(size * size):` and removed line `row, col = row + directions[direction][0], col + directions[direction][1]`

Comment: What I mean is on the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/CRFrihf

Comment: The change to `[(0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1)]` is wrong. The last two entries are in the wrong order. I don't know why you changed the loop that way, because obviously the number of asterisks doesn't change by changing to anti-clockwise. And I am lost why you'd *remove* a line of code. Sure anti-clockwise would need the same number of statements as clockwise. If you cannot make it work, post a new question.

Comment: Oh, such a ... . I'm so sorry. I really didn't realise I was wrong with the change of directions list. And started doing strange things